# cant add column to table using php7.0

Tags: php, sql

Hi i want to add a new column to a table named tasks using php.
ive tried multiple things but when i go into phpmyadmin no new columns are there.
:current code

```
<?php
$date = date("d/m/Y");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "webdata 2";
$username = "admin";
$password = "********";

// Create connection

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection

if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "";

$sql = "INSERT INTO tasks (username) VALUES ('$ip')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
     echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: your command is to add new row. not new column. To add new column, you must use ALTER command.

Answer (score 0):

The code you write is for add new row if you want to add a new column you need to change the variable `$sql` to this code

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE table_name ADD [COLUMN] column_name column_definition";
```

for more information, you can find at this  [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-add-column/)